# Why Google Location Service not working in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome

Why Google location services are not working? I already have the code which is working perfectly in browsers other than Chrome. It was working in Chrome till last Wednesday. And not only this, it is indeed not working for any other site who have used this code. Is this due to SSL?

As an example, please visit http://stores.hypethegym.com/hype-sector-4-gurgaon-339/Map

When you open this page, you should get a notification saying "Share your location" in firefox & IE10, but in Chrome, there is a problem.

We are getting following error in Chrome:

"getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS...."

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: what kind of error that you encountered in chrome?

Comment: Thanks @KENdi. Post updated with error. :)

Comment: Got the solution. We are not using a secured URL. Google have decrypted getCurrentPosition and watchPosition for URLs without https (insecure).